# How to check if a table / field is a richtext field in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3

How to check if a table / field is a richtext field in TYPO3?

In the BE or CLI context, I would like get all tables / fields which provide an RTE field.

Also, get all fields which support typolinks (e.g. `t3://page?uid?123` syntax).

Use cases are, for example:

- convert all links in rich text fields which use an absolute URL to a file / page on the site to typolinks (e.g. <a href="https://mysite" => <a href="t3://page?uid=1).

---

There are a bunch of configuration options,  most notably enableRichtext, richtextConfiguration, softref. Is it sufficient to check enableRichtext?

Answer (score 0):

*This is a preliminary self-answer - I am using the following methods, but there may be things I have not yet considered.*

---

All these need to be considered:

1. check **enableRichtext**

   A simple check is to check the [enableRichtext](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Text/Properties/EnableRichtext.html) field in TCA, e.g. `$GLOBALS['TCA'][$table]['columns'][$field]['config']['enableRichtext']`.

   However, this will not get all the results, most notably `tt_content.bodytext` (where this option is not set)!
2. also consider the **columnsOverrides** for **types** (if defined)

   For this field, the result is not always the same, in depends on the `CType` field. It is defined by the [type](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/Type.html) in `$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['ctrl']['type']` that CType is to be used as type field for tt_content.

   The additional configuration based on type is then found in `$GLOBALS['TCA'][$table]['types']` which contains the following for the table / field `tt_content.bodytext` for the type "textmedia":

   `$GLOBALS['TCA'][$table]['types']`:

   ```
    'textmedia' => [
        'columnsOverrides' => [
            'bodytext' => [
                'config' => [
                    'enableRichtext' => 1, 
                ]   
            ]  
        ]      
    ];
   ```

   So, checking for richtext must always include the type if defined for the table. For an example, where this is configured differently, see the html element in tt_content (`$GLOBALS['TCA'][$table]['types']['html']['columnsOverrides']['bodytext']['config']:

   ```
   [
       'format' => 'html',
       'renderType' => 't3editor',
   ]
   ```
3. Also check softref

   Additionally, if checking if typolinks are supported for the field, one can check the "softref" field `$GLOBALS['TCA'][$table]['columns'][$field]['config']['softref']`. If this contains `typolink_tag`, typolinks should be supported. It may look like this:

   ```
   typolink_tag,email[subst],url
   ```

   This might also get overridden by a specific type as described in 2.
4. You may also want to check if a BE has the RTE configured if this is relevant, e.g. with

   ```
   $backendUser->isRTE();
   ```

---

An alternative and possibly better solution is to use [FormEngine](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/FormEngine/DataCompiling/Index.html) to process. For example if the TCA configuration `richtextConfiguration` is checked directly in TCA, overrides by Page TSconfig are not considered. If you use the FormEngine mechanism (which for example does TCA preprocessing), everything can be applied in the same way as TYPO3 uses it in the backend. However, this is less simple to use and has its own pitfalls (e.g. requires a request object since TYPO3 v13).

---

*Tested for TYPO3 v11.*

### Further information

- TYPO3 core class `TYPO3\CMS\RteCKEditor\Form\Resolver\RichTextNodeResolver`
- TYPO3 documentation: [enableRichtext](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Text/Properties/EnableRichtext.html) (TCA)
- TYPO3 documentation: [softref](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/CommonProperties/Softref.html?highlight=softref) (TCA)
- TYPO3 documentation: [richtextConfiguration](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Text/Properties/RichtextConfiguration.html) (TCA)
- TYPO3 documentation: [RTE](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/12.4/en-us/PageTsconfig/Rte.html) (TSconfig)
- TYPO3 documentation: [ctrl => type](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/Type.html) (TCA)
- TYPO3 documentation: [types](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Types/Index.html) (TCA)
- TYPO3 documentation: [FormEngine data compiling](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/FormEngine/DataCompiling/Index.html)

Comment: to check if a field provides the conversion of typolinks, you had to parse the fluid-templates, to get reliable info. And if there are individual `parseFunc`s integrated you had to parse them too. also you had to make sure that `lib.parseFunc` and `lib.parseFunc_RTE` are not altered or can parse the links.
So to give a 100% reliable assessment, it's quite a complicated work.

Comment: If you have a different solution it might be helpful to give give an answer as well. I don't quite understand why parsing Fluid templates would be necessary here. Is that something that is done in the BE? I don't want to parse the links, I just want to know IF typolink syntax is supported for a particular field / record.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the need yet and never thought about the problem. Concerning TCA your approach looks good, and it might provide at least a clue which viewhelpers in fluid templates can / should be used. I suppose any work in the direction of my ideas had to build up on your ideas additionally, so it was no objection or call for an alternative solution ;-)